# Ktor returns 415 from endpoints where receive() is used with ContentNegotiation

Tags: kotlin, ktor, content-negotiation

I have parameter classes with the @Searializable annotation:

```
@Serializable
data class ShowPostURL(
        val date: String,
        val titleSlug: String,
        override val redirectTo: String? = null
)
```

and no matter what I do `call.receive()` won't work. I'm getting  HTTP 415 errors and Ktor doesn't log anything. I've added the serialization support as well:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()
}
```

How do I fix this? This is how I'm trying to use it:

```
accept(ContentType.Any) {
    get("/foo/{date}/{titleSlug}") {
        val input = call.receive(ShowPostURL::class)
        call.respondText("foo")
    }
}
```

If I do a trace I can see that my route is matched, but it can't receive the parameters. Is this `json()` setup is supposed to work when I'm deserializing from url parameters like this?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `ContentNegotiation` feature works only for receiving custom objects from the payload of **POST**, **PUT** and **PATCH** requests:

> POST, PUT and PATCH requests have an associated request body (the payload). That payload is usually encoded.
> In order to receive custom objects from the payload, you have to use the [ContentNegotiation](https://ktor.io/servers/features/content-negotiation.html#receiving) feature. This is useful for example to receive and send JSON payloads in REST APIs.
> When receiving, the `Content-Type` of the request will be used to determine which `ContentConverter` will be used to process that request

Secondly, there are three out of the box `ContentConverter` available:
[GsonConverter](https://ktor.io/servers/features/content-negotiation/gson.html), [JacksonConverter](https://ktor.io/servers/features/content-negotiation/jackson.html) and [SerializationConverter](https://ktor.io/servers/features/content-negotiation/serialization-converter.html).
Each of these converters has its own configuration function: `gson`, `jackson` and `serialization` respectively. You use `json` configuration function which is most likely is not appropriate for the configuration of `ContentNegotiation`.

To solve your problem you can access URL parameters by referring them with `call.parameters` and manually create `ShowPostURL` object. Then serialize it with the `kotlinx.serialization` framework if needed.

Also, you can write your own [ContentConverter](https://ktor.io/servers/features/content-negotiation.html#content-converter) to implement custom logic for [receiving typed objects](https://ktor.io/servers/calls/requests.html#typed-objects).

Comment: I'm using `json` becuase the official documentation says so. I discussed this on the Kotlin Slack and a JetBrains guy said that this feature it not yet supported, you can't deserialize objects from urls at all.